# Dynamic Button in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to code my own website. But I had a problem with a button. Here is my code;

```
<div *ngFor="let game of games" class=card">
   <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-tittle">{{game.name}}</h5>
     <p class="card-text">{{game.description}}</p>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/games/details/{{game.name}}"> Game Details</button>
   </div>
```

My question is, how can I make this "Game Details" button dynamic? What I am trying to say is, if someone presses it with a game called "COD Black OPS", it should display the "COD Black Ops" part of the json on the new page and if someone presses it with a game called "FIFA", it should display the "FIFA" part of the json on the new page. Here is an image to avoid the confission;
[Design of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiLOj.png). As I have said, when someone presses "Game Details" at COD Black Ops card, it directs to gameDetails component, but how will I dynamically carry the names of the games to that domponent?

Thank you from now :)

PS: There is only one gameDetails component. What I think is that if I can get the game names dynamically, I can filter the details of the selected game from json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a **Service**.

Service is a JavaScript class and includes properties and methods to share the data between components.

Example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Game } from '../models/game';

@Injectable()

export class SelectedGameService {

  selectedGame: Game;
  constructor() { }  
}
```

Add this in `providers` in module.

```
import { SelectedGameService } from './selected-game.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [SelectedGameService ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

And then inject this into your components.

```
import { SelectedGameService } from './selected-game.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router,
private selectedGameService : SelectedGameService ){}

  handleDetailsClick(game) {
   this.selectedGameService = game;
   this.router.navigate([`details/{game.id}`]);
  }
}
```

Similarly inject into details components and access the data.

Then it's all connected. You modify the data of the service in one component, move to other component and easily access the data of the service.

I have created a working example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsovts-service-example

Comment: Thanks you a lot for this wonderful answer, since I am new to Angular, I guess it should help me a lot if you can create stackblitz if its not going to be a trouble for you

Comment: Sure. I will create one.

Comment: Updated my answer with the stackblitz. Please accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

instead of having a routerlink directly on button better to call method on click of button like : `<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="routeToDetailPage(game.name)"> Game Details</button>`
and in your component, inject Router and ActivatedRoute. 
Your method will go something like :

```
routeToDetailPage(gameName){
this.router.navigate([`./games/details/${gameName}`],
{
    relativeTo:this.activatedRoute,
    state:{data:gameName}
}
)};
```

In detail Page you can access route data using history and history.state.